# Trouble getting tesseract to work on python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm having some trouble when I try to run a code using tesseract on jupyter notebook or on pycharm. I suspect is a problem with the installation on Windows 7 but I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

So I've tried many different thing, from pip install tesseract and pytesseract to install tesseract OCR (at first I've thought is was just a library that's why I've messed up the order) following this: 
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki
I've actually downloaded this Cygwin and MSYS2 although I've saw some youtube videos in which they didn't install those.
And I even path the right address on my system.

Ok so I'm using a simple code just exemplify:

```
from PIL import Image                                                           
import pytesseract

img = Image.open("teste.png")
print(img)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)                              
print ('Image text:', text)
```

The error message is pretty big but I think it resume itself at this line:

```
TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR is not installed or it's not in your path
```

Problem is that I did path it at:
Environment variables - path - edit - %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem; %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR

And I know is installed because I can run it from cmd...

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? Try setting `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd` to your `tesseract.exe` path

Comment: The thing is that pytesseract.image_to_string calls the run_tesseract function, which kicks off a subprocess that calls the tesseract executable. Check https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract#installation to install and config it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always have trouble with pytesseract in Windows unless I tell it where the executable is:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks a lot man. That was the problem...
Not sure why that happens even after I've path it. Thanks a lot bfris!! And thanks also to the other guys who tried to help